# Prepared Statement Database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I want to write data from a JTable into a databse, but it does not work so far.
I always get an mysql Error! Someone could tell me what is wrong?

```
public class Fussball extends JFrame {

    private JButton save = new JButton();
    private JTable jTable1 = new JTable(9, 4);
    private DefaultTableModel jTable1Model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    private JScrollPane jTable1ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable1);

    public Fussball(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        int frameWidth = 563;
        int frameHeight = 482;
        setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
        int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
        setLocation(x, y);
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(null);
        // Anfang Komponenten
        save.setBounds(200, 304, 201, 65);
        save.setText("speichern");
        save.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                save_ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        cp.add(save);
        jTable1ScrollPane.setBounds(64, 48, 465, 225);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("Spiel ID");
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("Verein 1");
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setHeaderValue("Verein 2");
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setHeaderValue("Ergebnis");
        cp.add(jTable1ScrollPane);
        // Ende Komponenten
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void save_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fussball", "root", "");
            Statement statement = dbConn.createStatement();
            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Spiel VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            ps.setString(1, "idSpiel");
            ps.setString(2, "Vereinone");
            ps.setString(3, "Vereintwo");
            ps.setString(4, "Ergebnis");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            //Vector vector = new Vector();
            statement.close();
            dbConn.close();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.err.println("Error in Instantiation!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Class not found!");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.err.println("Access denied!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQL Error!");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Fussball("fussball");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: What error you're getting?

Comment: When you're using try catch statements, it usually helps to just print the stack trace, rather than just giving a vague output about the nature of the exception.

Comment: To learn more about the SQLException, print it in the catch clause (instead of only "SQL Error!"). THe latter is like, "es druckt nicht!" - nobody can help you with that.

Comment: My guess could be `ps.setString(1, "idSpiel");` could be creating problem. As it looks like id it has to be some digit values. If its auto incremented then you should have skip that column. As other suggested use `e.printStacktrace()` in catch block to get detailed info about exception and close your statements in `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate the database functionality away from your UI code. Just write a simple method to run an insert like you have your listener method doing and see if you can get it to work. You are almost doing that now since the code you posted does not actually pull data from the table. It looks like it just runs a test update. Still, I recommend that you create a DAO class and place all of your SQL code there instead of mixed in with your UI code.

The error messages from SQL are not always that helpful, but sometimes they are. You are ignoring the Exception in your code.

In particular, I would replace the catch block in your code with this:

```
 catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQL Error:" + e.toString() );
 }
```

Also note that you are not using your `Statement statement = dbConn.createStatement();` so you can just delete that line.

Within your DAO class, you could create a test method like so to help us isolate and troubleshoot this issue. It's important to display exception messages rather than just catching them and printing your own message.

```
 public void testDBInsert() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fussball", "root", "");
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Spiel VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        ps.setInt(1, 128);  //should be an integer?
        ps.setString(2, "Vereinone");
        ps.setString(3, "Vereintwo");
        ps.setString(4, "Ergebnis");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        dbConn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error in SQL Test: " + e.toString() );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Classpath` to the folder containing MYSQL JDBC driver and re-run your application

Answer (score 0):

> If I´m not mistaken, the statement you are using is wrong:
>
> ```
> private final String INSERT_QUERY=
> "INSERT INTO tableName (col_name,col_name2, col_name3) VALUES(?, ?, ?);";
> ```
>
> You are missing the names of the columns you want associated to the values.

Eddited: The **ABOVE** is false, both your statement and mine are correct.

Also, if you are using and INSERT statement, you can just do (you don´t have to create a statement):

```
PreparedStatement p = dbConn.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY);
p.setString(...);
```

So on so forth.

If that doesn´t help, there´s also (which has happened to me plenty of times) the fact that your MySQL Server might be turned off (not running). Check that it is running first.

If none works, could you at least try to give us the error you are getting?

Comment: neither your statement  'INSERT INTO tableName....' and his statement not wrong you can specify column names or not it's optional.